# func_get_args VS ...$params

Tags: php, function, parameters

before php 5.6 we used to get params using func_get_args() , but php 5.6 supports the new operator (...$params)

i always prefer using the old style to make sure that my code is compatible with the old versions of php ,

but there is a little problem , does using a function without params and implement this function with a different number of params will cause an E_STRICT error?

so what is better for me now?

```
function test(...$params){
//only supported in php 5.6

function test(){
$params=func_get_args();
//may cause an E_STRICT error
}
```

Comment: Well, it's not better to use a deprecated function.

Comment: func_get_args() is not deprecated
http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php